# Visual studio error while creating asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I get following error when I create blank, web api project using VS 2017.[image]

I tried after rebooting my machine as well but of no help. Any clue?

Comment: Sometimes windows scrambeles the rights on Folders. And VS likes to run programms under rather exotic user accounts. And "Another prcoess is using it" could be the fallback error message, like "file not found" was in programms written for FAT32 running into User Rights.

Comment: this link maybe help you :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34134424/asp-net-web-api-2-internet-explorer-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-becaus

Comment: @mehdifarhadi I am very sorry but the link you have provided is a completely different problem.

Comment: Use Process Explorer to figure out what else might be using it https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-find-out-which-windows-process-using-file.htm